How to add hours in existing datetime field in expression in ADF pipeline?

I was trying the above expression in the ADF but unable to get the datetime field values with 4 hours minus in the current datetime field, instead it is showing NULL values. Any help on this would he here?
Thank you in advance,
I was trying the above expression in the ADF but unable to get the datetime field values with 4 hours minus in the current datetime field, instead it is showing NULL values.

You can use below expression in derived column expression builder to get the datetime field values with 4 hours minus in the current datetime field:
toTimestamp(toString(currentTimestamp()), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') + (days(0) -  hours(4) +  seconds(0)) 

You will get your required output as shown below:

For more information you can refer to the MS document.
